# UITableView to always show 4 cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, resize, retina-display

I want my UITableView to always show 4 rows, whether it's on retina 3.5 or 4 - with appropriate re-sizing of fonts and subviews in the cell.  The app will always be in portrait orientation.

Is there an "elegant" way to do this in storyboard or through constraints?

Or is the best way to determine all the sizes manually, then alter them programmatically?

Comment: it sounds like what you *really* want here is for the cell heights to change dynamically depending on how tall the screen is in whatever orientation it's in, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Auto-resize property of UITableView with flexible height, so that it could change height on devices having different screen sizes. Use *heightForRowAtIndexPath* like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.yourTableView.frame.size.height/4;
}
```

Now, whatever the height of tableview is, you will get same cell heights for all 4 cells.

Note: For your *UITableViewCells* set view and elements resize properties like flexible height and flexible positions, so that cells' elements get adjusted according to height changes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question, but if you want to specify the cell height, you can use a  *UITableViewDelegate* method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```